# Copy a range of cells based on a value and insert them on another sheet

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm new to using VBA and don't fully understand how to use the range and offset functions.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have a worksheet "Sheet1" that has product and pricing information in columns "A" thru "H" starting at row 4.  Column "D" is the quantity that is entered.  I'm trying to write a macro so that whatever row has a number in column "D" it will then **insert** the cells "A" thru "D" of that row on to "Sheet4" starting at "B49".  There are rows with information both before and after "B49" that I don't want to overwrite.

Here is the code that I have to copy the cells:

```
Sub Copy_And_Paste()
'
' Copy_And_Paste Macro
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow

    If Cells(i, 4) > 0 Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("B49").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Right now it only paste the first line with a number in column "D".

Comment: `starting at "B49". There are rows with information both before and after "B49" that I don't want to overwrite` So you just keep pasting over data??

Comment: So, if there are 10 rows with a quantity in column "D" on "Sheet1" then the information on "Sheet4" in "B50" will now be in "B60".

Comment: I still don't understand :/ You want to insert rows?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: So add an `.insert`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a lot of experience with VBA so when you say add an '.insert', I don't know where to add it or the other parts of the code that go with it.

Comment: Did you write the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work the way I wanted by taking out the `LastRow` statement and changing the `For i` statement to

```
For i =10000 To 4 Step -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
Sub Copy_And_Paste()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To LastRow
            If .Cells(i, 4) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Sheet4").Rows(49).Insert
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 4)).Copy Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B49")
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, this worked but it transfers the rows from bottom to top because it keeps inserting the lines at "B49" and shifting them down.  I would like it to insert the first line at "B49" and then the next one at "B50", then "B51" etc. Thanks for the help.